# How to add new script and wait for it to execute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom-events

Let's say I've got `my-file.js` or some CDN file in different server that has

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++) {
    //something really long and hard to execute
}
//after this long execution

window.myObj = { 
    //initialization of some global object that I need 
}
```

(I cannot change `my-file.js`...)

I want to add `my-file.js` **asynchronously**  to page, and then, after it is *loaded* **and** **EXECUTED** I want to call some event like:

```
//when my my-file.js is loaded I finally use window.myObj
window.myObj.somefunc(); //yaaay
```

Is it possible? (cross browser for IE9+ is important for me, but any not critical)

**Note:**
In case file I need is on CDN or somewhere on different server - I need to remember about cross-domain policy, so I think loading content of file in ajax is not possible in such case.

**Note 2:**
http://www.chromestatus.com/features/5711871906676736 there is exacly what I need, but I bet it'll be few years before you can easly use it globally.

Comment: What comprises "***and EXECUTED***"? It could have timers, AJAX calls etc. Should we also wait for those? Listening for when it loads is possible. When it fully executes is another thing.

Comment: In order to wait for execution, there would have to be some callback function call in `my-file.js`, or a variable update that you could monitor. Is there anything like that?

Comment: Joseph the Dreamer - no, we dont need to wait for all ajax calls. It could be useful in some cases tho.

Comment: Jonathan M - no, there is nothing like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.onload = function(){
  // loaded
}
document.head.appendChild(script);
script.src = "path/to/script";
```

That's about the simplest example. And yes, the entire thing is async, hence it needed the `onload` handler.

You could also wrap it up in a function:

```
function getScript(src,callback){
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = callback;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
}

getScript('path/to/js',function(){
  //loaded
});
```

However, thinking out of the box, it sounds like you need dependency management. Use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). Should fit your needs.

Comment: It waits for script to load, not to execute. If script you're loading takes a while to execute, and you'll try to use globals it create just after your code, it'll fail. Try it with some huge loop.

Comment: My example handles that

Comment: @AdamPietrasiak What you seem to need is dependency management (*load and run this before that*). Use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org) instead.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery getScript has a callback you can use to execute events after a file is loaded, or you can use script.onload as in Joseph's example:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

If you want to wait until a certain property is available (ie after some work has finished), you can create an interval and then clear it as soon as the property is found in window, ie:

```
var waitForObj = setInterval(function(){
  if(window.myObj && window.myObj.somefunc){
    clearInterval(waitForObj);
    //Do some stuff you need this object for
  }
}, 100);
```

Comment: It works only on same-domain policy. When you'll try to use it on some cdn without cross-domain allowed -> fail.